# Can this MVC code be refactored using a design pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, events, design-patterns

I've got controller code like this all over my ASP.NET MVC 3 site:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PostViewModel viewModel)
{
   // VM -> Domain Mapping. Definetely belongs here. Happy with this.
   var post = Mapper.Map<PostViewModel, Post>(viewModel);

   // Saving. Again, fine. Controllers job to update model.
   _postRepository.Save(post);

   // No. Noooo..caching, thread spawning, something about a user?? Why....
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       _cache.RefreshSomeCache(post);
       _cache2.RefreshSomeOtherCache(post2);
       _userRepository.GiveUserPoints(post.User);
       _someotherRepo.AuditThisHappened();
   });

   // This should be the 3rd line in this method.
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Basically, i'm referring to the code in the threading block. All things need to happen, but the user doesn't need to wait for them (good case for a background thread, right?).

Just to be clear, i use caching (regular ASP.NET data cache) all over the site, and most of this has a "no expire" cache policy, so i manually evict it when required (like the above).

And the user part is basically giving user rep for doing something (like Stack).

So let's recap: we have caching, user reputation handling, auditing, all in one. Doesn't really belong in one spot does it. Hence the problem with the current code, and the problem with trying to figure out how to move it away.

The reason i want to refactor this is for a few reasons:

1. Difficult to unit test. Multithreading and unit testing doesn't really play nice.
2. Readability. It's hard to read. Messy.
3. SRP. Controller doing/knowing too much.

I solved 1) by wrapping the thread spawning code into an interface, and just mocking/faking that out.

But i would like to do some kind of pattern, where my code could look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PostViewModel viewModel)
{
   // Map.
   var post = Mapper.Map<PostViewModel, Post>(viewModel);

   // Save.
   _postRepository.Save(post);

   // Tell someone about this.
   _eventManager.RaiseEvent(post);

   // Redirect.
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Basically, putting the onus on "something else" to react, not the controller.

I've heard/read about Tasks, Commands, Events, etc but have yet to see one implemented in the ASP.NET MVC space.

First thoughts would tell me to create some kind of "event manager". But then i thought, where does this go? In the domain? Well then how does it handle interactions with the cache, which is an infrastructure concern. And then threading, which is also an infrastructure concern. And what if i want to do is synchronously, instead of async? What makes that decision?

I don't want to have to just pile all this logic somewhere else. It ideally should be re factored into manageable and meaningful components, not shifted responsbility, if that makes sense.

Any advice?

Comment: +1 this is a good question to a common problem. i expect to see n+1 solutions offered. where to go thereafter... hmmm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First thoughts would tell me to create some kind of "event manager". But then i thought, where does this go? In the domain?

It's the way I solve the problem. I see the event manager as infrastructure. But the actual events belongs in the domain.

> Well then how does it handle interactions with the cache, which is an infrastructure concern. And then threading, which is also an infrastructure concern. And what if i want to do is synchronously, instead of async? What makes that decision?

Async is nice, but makes transaction handling complex. If you use an IoC container you already have a well defined scope and a transaction which can be used during the event propagation.

imho it's up to the subscriber to schedule/thread it's task if it knows that it's event handling will take time.

**Proposed solution:**

Use your IoC container to publish the events. I would let the repository publish the events (either `PostUpdated` or `EntityUpdated` depending on what you want to do with the event) rather than the controller (to reduce code duplication).

I've made an IoC implementation for autofac which allows you to:

```
DomainEventDispatcher.Current.Dispatch(new EntityUpdated(post));
```

Subscription:

```
public class CacheService : IAutoSubscriberOf<EntityUpdated>
{
    public void Handle(EntityUpdated domainEvent) {};
}
```

https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/wiki/Domain-events

**Typical usage**

1. Implement [IServiceResolver](https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/blob/master/source/Sogeti.Pattern/Sogeti.Pattern.Core/InversionOfControl/IServiceResolver.cs) (for your container)
2. Assign it: `ServiceResolver.Assign(new yourResolver(yourContainer))`
3. Use as described [here](https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/wiki/Domain-events).

Comment: interesting. but then how does threading go into the mix? Would the cache need to fire the thread?

Comment: kind of. i just need to have a play when i get into work, and figure out how to do this with my DI container (StructureMap). Stay tuned...

Comment: looking at your github code, seems like a lot of code for me to try and port over to StructureMap. Do you know of any existing nuget/resources that do this in structuremap? I don't want to have to spend a lot of time rolling my own StructureMap event manager.

Comment: The only code you have to port is this class: https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/blob/master/source/Sogeti.Pattern/Sogeti.Pattern.Core.Autofac/AutofacServiceResolver.cs You can use the `Sogeti.pattern.code` nuget package for the rest.

Comment: do you have anywhere where you have documented the typical usage of this library in a MVC app? Doesn't seem to any info/doco on the nuget site. I've installed the package, but how do i use it? Obviously i need to make some DI changes, etc...but is there an example MVC site you have up and running with Sogeti?

Comment: in the meantime i've found this, which seems promising: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52810/Event-Aggregator-with-Specialized-Listeners

Comment: okay so i've done the following. 1) Installed (via nuget) `sogeti.pattern.core (0.0.4)`. 2) Updated my SM resolver to implement `IServiceResolver` (and set it up in Global.asax). 3) Created a simple class which implements `IDomainEvent`. 4) Made a service implement `IAutoSubscriberOf<SomeEvent>`. Raised that event in a controller action as described. No errors, but the handler isn't called. Is there something i've missed, or is there something i can debug/check for issues? Really appreciate all your help BTW. :)

Comment: i grabbed the git source, and added the project into my solution for debugging. It's in the `ServiceResolverDispatcher.Dispatch` method, but `ServiceResolver.Current.ResolveAll(type)` returns 0 items. Where `type` is `IAutoSubscriberOf<MyEvent>`. I'm definetely missing something.

Comment: nevermind, got it working. It was another StructureMap change i added. Accepted, and will add a seperate answer for StructureMap users.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps the post object should update itself, and be passed an IRepository (which itself was passed to the controller.) (this is basic dependency injection/IOC, and keeps the controller skinnier)

```
//in controller:
var post = Mapper.Map<PostViewModel, Post>(viewModel);
post.Update(_postRepository);

//inside Post.cs:
public Update(IRepository rep){
//update db with the repo    
//give points
}
```

Comment: a) Then the Post (domain) has a dependency on the repository, which even though arguably the repository is part of the domain, i like to keep my POCO's dumb. b) doesn't really solve the cache problem.

Comment: @RPM1984, it's DDD where the domain logic is inside the model.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - okay, well im not doing DDD then. :) But i want my POCOs with nothing but properties and business logic (internal), but not requiring external dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) on this particular problem. Commonly used product in the .NET world is [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

The idea would be that you add an attribute above the method. The attribute will tell what particular actions should be done (in your case cache refreshing, points to increase etc.) and when it should happen (in your case when exiting the method for example).

You could also separate these to different attributes, so you could make different kind of combinations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a message bus implementation in [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/), as part of the PortableArea feature. Its main purpose is to allow independently implemented features to trigger and listen for events, which sounds pretty much like what you desire.

I'm not sure if its the best option out there, as the state of MvcContrib is somewhat undocumented and sketchy. Some parts are actively maintained while others are obsolete.

Another option to consider is [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), but it may be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider implementing a service bus system such as [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/) if you are dealing with cache busting or auditing (that may be better served asynchronously).

With a message bus, event messages may be published to any number of event handlers (e.g. a cache handler) asynchronously, so your app can fire off a message, and then continue serving up synchronous pages quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to consider **transaction** issue. If you try to update caches in another thread and return the action result immediately after repository.save. It's hard to roll back if cache operations throws a error(most caches are global, which usually face with lock/sync problems).
2. MVC is a UI layer pattern. I usually put some http context based logic in the action body and put the business logic into lower layers, for example, a service, which handles domain model. In your case, I'd like to add a IPostService and put your save function and cached function in it. Which is something like:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Save(PostViewModel viewModel)
   {
      // Map.
      var post = Mapper.Map<PostViewModel, Post>(viewModel);

      // Save.
      _postService.Save(post);

      // Redirect.
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   ```

   And because cache is not related with the business logic, it does't need to appear in the service interface. It's an implementation detail.
3. Moreover, I think it's good to use AOP to trigger event and use an IoC container to inject the cache logic(along with transaction logic). Something like:

   ```
   //codes in your PostService which implements IPostService
   [CacheEvent("POST")]
   [Transaction]
   public void Save(Post post) //care about domain model instead of view model
   {
      // Save.
      _postReposity.Save(post);
   }
   ```

Comment: i used to have services, but i ripped them out because i realised they were just wrapping my repository and adding no value. i don't think the fact of moving the cache there warrants bringing it back in. thanks for the tip though. all useful advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted @jgauffin's answer, but thought i'd add a seperate answer since i use StructureMap, and it needed **one extra step**.

I followed what @jgauffin specified, but it wasn't firing my event handler.

So i added this to my StructureMap config:

```
x.Scan(y => 
{
   y.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
   y.AddAllTypesOf(typeof (IAutoSubscriberOf<>));
   y.WithDefaultConventions();
});
```

Then it works.

I'm guessing the alternative to this is to manually specify each registered listener, which gets a bit crazy.

Can someone who uses StructureMap tell me if this is the right approach?